# rynkeby faucet still not working

Tags: ether, rinkeby, faucets

rinkeby faucet still not working, someone can help me? if you can send me some eth to:0xaE9e1bd10F9C164f50cF9199697E4910641f0E11 I would be immensely grateful

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can to try this faucets:

- https://rinkebyfaucet.com/
- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Comment: thank you so much, the first link works!